# Keep HTML table order after page reload in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to keep the selected table ordering (ordered by a specific column and either ascending or descending) after reloading the page by using

```js
   function myController() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.orderBy = "col1";
        vm.orderTable = orderTable;
        vm.orderAsc = false;

     function loadPage() {            
            var orderedBy = localStorage.getItem("vm.orderedBy");
            if(orderedBy != null && orderedBy != "" && orderedBy != undefined) {
                orderTable(orderedBy);
            }
        }

    function orderTable(column) {
            if (column!= vm.orderBy) {
                vm.orderAsc = false;
                vm.orderBy = column;
            } else {
                vm.orderAsc = !vm.orderAsc;
            }
            localStorage.setItem("vm.orderedBy", vm.orderBy);
            localStorage.setItem("vm.orderedAsc", vm.orderAsc); 
        }
    }
```

but it's not working. It orders the table by the correct column but it is always in ascending order when the page is reloaded.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have also tried this: `function loadPage() {         
            var orderedBy = localStorage.getItem("vm.orderedBy");
            if(orderedBy != null && orderedBy != "" && orderedBy != undefined) {
                orderTableAfterRefresh(orderedBy);
            }
        }

        function orderTableAfterRefresh(column) {
            vm.orderBy = column;
            vm.orderAsc = localStorage.getItem("vm.orderedAsc");
        }`

Answer (score 0):

You should call the function on page load using the body tag.

e.g.

```
<body onload="yourOrderingFunction()">
```

When the page is loaded or reloaded it will keep the order that you have applied in your javascript.

Comment: It's not working. I think it's got something to do with Angular not properly repainting with the stored attributes in localStorage.